# If $\,a^2+b^2\,$ is a prime, how often is $\,(ab)^2+(a+b)^2\,$ a prime too?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For each prime $\;p\equiv 1\mod 4\;$ a unique decomposition exists as a sum of two squares $\;p=a^2+b^2$.

**I ask how often is $\,(ab)^2+(a+b)^2\,$ a prime too.**

If we obtain another prime we can repeat the procedure and, eventually, generate a chain of such primes. Up to the first $10^7$ primes, 4999454 primes are congruent to 1 (mod 4), and some computations have given the following results:

- just $1$ chain of lenght $7$ (starting with $\,p=2\,$ that, even if not congruent to $1$ (mod $4$), is equal to $\,1^2+1^2$)
- $5$ chains of lenght $6$ (starting with: $5, 23434781, 65715821, 165664753, 176884153$)
- $159$ chains of lenght $5$ ($0.0032$ %)
- $3750$ chains of lenght $4$ ($0.075$ %)
- $57989$ chains of lenght $3$ ($1.16$ %)
- $592927$ chains of lenght $2$ ($11.86$ %)

We may conjecture that:

- the lenght of the chains is upper bounded by $7$
- the only chain of lenght $7$ is the one starting from $\,p=2$ $(2, 5, 13, 61, 1021, 110581, 183198541)$
- there are infinitely many chains of lenght less than 7

Many thanks for any suggestion, comment or answer.

Comment: i doubt it will be possible to prove much.  By [Schinzel's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) we'd expect the polynomials $(2k)^2+1,8k^2+4k+1$ to take on simultaneously prime values for infinitely many $k$ which would certainly imply one of your conjectures, but of course this is nowhere near being proved.  Might be worth seeing why Schinzel doesn't imply the existence of chains of arbitrary length (my intuition would be that it did).

Comment: @lulu Can we translate a chain as described in the question into a chain of polynomials for which the generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture applies ? In this case, we can at least conjecture that the length is unbounded. For example, what are the polynomials for a chain of length $4$ ?

Comment: @Peter  Yes...at least, that's what I'd expect.  For my example, of course, I just looked at chains of length $2$.  To do length $3$ we'd want to add $(2k(2k+1))^2+(4k+1)^2$ to the list, and so on.  I don't see what goes wrong, if anything does.

Comment: For the record, there is another chain of length $7$ starting at $16042^2+2403^2=263120173$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'odds' that a random odd number $\lt 10^7$ is prime are roughly $2/\ln(10^7)\approx1/8$, which comes pretty close to your 11.8% figure. I suspect there's nothing known about this but I would expect them to follow the heuristics. If I'm doing my pre-coffee math correctly, then since abstractly the number you're hoping to be prime is of size $\approx p^2$, heuristically it seems as though chains of arbitrary fixed length should exist: for all $p$, the heuristic probability of a chain of length $n$ starting from $p$ is $\displaystyle\approx \frac1{\ln p}\cdot\frac1{\ln(p^2)}\cdots\frac1{\ln(p^{2^n})} \approx \frac1{2^{n^2/2}\ln^np}$. The constant term is smaller, but this is broadly akin to the probability for [Cunningham Chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of length $n$.

Comment: For a pre-coffee math, this doesn't look bad at all:)